# Compositing multiple scenes and passes with transparency

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes

I am trying to composite some render layers from two different scenes:

Main scene has objects and mist pass, transparency in world setting enabled.
Sky scene has only sky environment and transparency in world setting disabled.

What I want to achieve is to have the sky in the transparent area of the main scene, and to use the mist pass to add mist to the objects but not the sky, it should only affect the objects.

Main scene with objects:

[image: main objects with transparency]

Main scene mist pass

[image]

Sky scene

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the alpha channel of the trees renderlayer as a mix factor between the sky and the trees:

[image]

You can combine the *Mist pass* with the trees however you like, just replace the screen node with whatever nodes you want.

Comment: Ah I got it now, I was trying to do it all with only one mix node and over complicating things.