# One render layer with background image and one with transparent background

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, render-layers

I made an animation with an environment texture in the background and I would like to have one render layer with only the background image and another render layer with all the objects on a transparent background.

I tried to uncheck the "Use Environment" on the objects render layer, but this rendered the objects on a black background (not transparent). On the other side if I set the film to transparent in the render settings, then the objects are on a transparent background (as I want), but the background layer is empty.

I use Cycles for rendering.

Comment: This is usually achieved by enabling "Transparency" in Film panel (to get the foreground) as you did and "Environment" in Passes panel (to store the background). See related questions: [Sky-only pass with the foreground knocked out?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33445/sky-only-pass-with-the-foreground-knocked-out/33457#33457) and [How can I combine two render layers?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21440/how-can-i-combine-two-render-layers/21443#21443)

Comment: @Carlo Thank you, it works! (I didn't notice that there is another environment option in the passes)

Comment: Good! "Use Environment" is an option that merely control the influence of the background on the scene (reflections, lighting...).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Enable Transparent on the Film section and enable environment on your render passes. The background environment will be avalible by connecting the environment socket.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! (Carlo was faster, but he only commented, so I will accept this...)

Answer (score 1):

One thing to keep in mind: if you render the Environment pass on the same layer as your foreground object, the shadow catcher plane will cut a hole in the Environment pass. This is bad if you want to then composite your foreground over the Environment as a background, as the area covered by the shadow catcher will be missing!

[image: Same Layer Env Pass]

In this scenario, instead render the Env pass on a 2nd render layer and composite as shown above by Cegaton:

[image: Blender shadow catcher - render background separate]