# Alpha over layers but maintain environment background

Tags: compositing-nodes, transparency, render-layers

I have a scene where I have a few different render layers that I need to put on top of each other for the final render. Everything works fine when I have transparent background checked for the render but I need to also have the environment background image behind everything. Also, the camera moves and displays different parts of the background, so I can't just alpha over everything on top of an image texture. Is this possible? Thanks in advance!

Comment: you could add another render layer that only have the environment background pass enabled and compose it underneath the other layers

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42470/one-render-layer-with-background-image-and-one-with-transparent-background/42471#42471

Answer (score 4):

Enable Environment in the render layers.

[image]

Enable Film, transparent.

[image]

Then composite your layers with transparency together, and place them over the Environment using Alpha Over.

[image]

Comment: Could you attach a .blend please, I can't reproduce your results, my background won't show up. I tested this in a recent daily build.