# Composite interior and exterior separately

Tags: compositing-nodes, render-layers

I'm trying to make an interior scene where I want to composite the exterior separetely form the interior. So, before I go any further I want to set up the layers to accomplish this.

In Layer 1 I've got just the **interior**:

[image: Layer 1]

Layer 2, the **Sun** and the **Earth** without the atmosphere:

[image]

Layer 3, just the **Atmosphere**, which I need to blur.

[image]

How can I composite the interior and the exterior separately and the join them?
 I'm fairly new to compositing so I don't have a clear idea to do this, specially with the window in the way.

---

**EDIT:**

This is how I've set up the three different render layers:

**Layer 1:**

[image: Render Layer 1]

**Layer 2:**

[image: Render Layer 2]

**Layer 3:**

[image: Render Layer 3]

And this is the result using the Alpha Overlay in the Compositer:

[image: Compositor]

Thanks,

Comment: The first thing you have to do is to enable film> transparent and get rid of the background (the stars and sky) on the first image, and use it as a separate element. Then use Alpha over to composite the layers in the order you need them. See this related links: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57610/alpha-over-layers-but-maintain-environment-background/57612#57612 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38452/cycles-not-rendering-image-or-movie-clip-used-as-background-in-the-viewport/38464#38464 For the atmosphere layer use a color mix node as add or screen mode

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38333/background-image-shows-in-front-of-3d-objects-not-behind-them/38334#38334

Comment: @cegaton I can't get it to work, there's no transparency in the first layer (because of the window?)

Comment: It's hard to guess how you set things up. All we know about your project is what you've posted so far. How did you create the background?

Comment: @cegaton It's just an HDR, please, tell me what else do you need and I'll update my question.

Comment: please read the links posted on my comments. The info you need is there.

Comment: @cegaton I've already tried the links but it's not working for me, or I'm doing something wrong, I've updated my question with the layers and the result in the compositor.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73013/discussion-between-cegaton-and-cuoka).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of Cegaton I've found the solution. The main problem was that the window is in the way so it has to be rendered separately. This way there's a hole in the first layer without the background so later on the `Alpha Over node` can be used.

So, in this case, four render layers are necessary:

**Layer 1:**

In this layer is the foreground, just the spaceship but without the Window, masking the rest so that there's a transparent hole in the window.

[image: Layer 1]

**Layer 2:**

In this layer it's the Earth without the Atmosphere.

[image: Layer 2]

**Layer 3:**

Just the atmosphere in layer three.

[image: Layer 3]

**Layer 4:**

Here is the Window:

[image: Layer 4]

---

And finally, here's the **compositor** node setup:

[image: Compositor]